# Change detection between modules in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

Imagine I have a multi-module maven project like :

```
project/
pom.xml
├── moduleA/
│   ├── src/main/java/my/package/InterfaceA.java
│   └── pom.xml
├── moduleB/
│   ├── src/main/java/my/package/ClassB.java
│   └── pom.xml
```

ModuleB depends on ModuleA, and ClassB implements InterfaceA.
If I change InterfaceA, IntelliJ does not detect that ClassB need some attention until I open myself ClassB in the editor.

Is it a normal behaviour ? I was hoping the IDE will detect that the dependent code not compile anymore and throw an error in the navigation tree to show me the impact.

Do I miss something ?

Comment: How did you import the project into IntelliJ? Did you import the modules separately or import the root pom?

Comment: I'm importing the root pom

Comment: Please try to set "external.system.substitute.library.dependencies = true" option
via "Help | Edit Custom Properties" and restart. Will it help?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but no, I still have to open the file with build error to make intellij detect this buid error.

Comment: Is it possible to share sample project example for investigation?

Comment: I've since understand that IntelliJ does not work as Eclipse : errors are not shown in the navigation tree even if the error could be detected and appears in the problems view.

Even in the problems view, errors sometime take some times to appears (maybe when a background build happens ?).
I'll see if I can accommodate with this behavior :)